# How do I implement ZigBee in Android?

Tags: android

We want to implement [ZigBee](http://www.zigbee.org/) in an Android tablet using a Texas Instrument cc2530m ZigBee soc. The tablet already worked, and we have a ZigBee driver and a stack driver. How can we develop an application for home automation profile with ZigBee?

Comment: Well presumably you would connect it to the tablet somehow (does the tablet have a USB host port?), load an appropriate driver into the kernel, and then write some user mode software to accomplish something, either in native code or java...

Comment: Yes it have an USB port, and i have an application compiles in a c nativ code on the android and i use a texas instrument cc2531 zigbee usb dongle now. The c program (called ZAP) works well in cosole mode on android, but i want to make it communicate with a real android application, normally on a standard linux we can use pipes, shared memory to make an interprocessus communication, but here i don't know realy how to make the both communicate.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few android tablets with integrated Zigbee Module (http://www.geekland.co/Zigbee-Tablets_c69.htm) that use serial port to communicate with the zigbee module. You can write a Java app that writes commands as messages to the serial port and have the firmware (developed on the chip) to translate the messages to appropriate zigbee commands.

Answer (score 2):

You can use most of the standard unix IPC mechanisms such as pipes or unix domain sockets with android.   While android adds its own binder IPC mechanism that would be fairly tricky to use from the "command line" portion of your solution, pipes & sockets should be readily accessible from java-like app code.  You shouldn't even need an NDK helper to do the communication, though you can use one if you prefer.

The more recent android tablets with official USB host under honeycomb have a user-mode usb host management API where you can talk directly to usb devices from within application code (ironically, that mechanism does not support writing drivers in native code!)